Unity C# Textmesh pro is not updating when changing text programatically
I have a TextMeshPro object for output and i want to change its text. What i found is that the text is changing but not updating. The weird thing is that i can change it and it updates when it is on start but later on when i try to change it , it does change but do not update.
The TextMeshPro object is inside a canvas so i am using an TextMeshProUGUI. TextMeshPro cannot be used cause it does not allow me to drag and drop the object. Tried also delcaring it with get component at start but it gets worse and text dont even change therefore it dont update.
the only way i found is that when changing the width of the rect transform manually then it updates..
found similar discussions but no solution.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/textmesh-pro-is-not-updating-when-changing-text-programatically.490125/
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI myOutput;


myOutput.text = "msg";    


To recreate the issue.
Create a canvas and a TMP inside. Create a script with the code
 [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI myOutput; 

then i added a button, when clicked to call a function where i put
myOutput.text = "msg"; 

Create object to add the script. Add the object to the button and select the function created previously.
Used a debug , reaches there but do not updates.
Unity version 2022.3.30f1

Please include the necessary steps to reproduce the issue.

well other than that wont be the whole code, some debugging would probably lead you down the right path

@hijinxbassist  Create a canvas and a TMP inside. Create a script with the code
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI myOutput;
then i added a button, when clicked to call a function where i put myOutput.text = "msg";
Create object to add the script. Add the object to the button and select the function created previously.

@hijinxbassist so in short words. click the button to change the text to "msg"

have you confirmed the function with your text change runs? by putting a debug message in it? any errors, warnings?

That all works as expected.  Please do further debugging as suggested by @BugFinder  Please do updates in the question and not as comments, so others can benefit from the additional information without digging around.  Including TMP version, Unity version, and your platform may also be helpful if you are still experiencing the problem after exhausting debugging.

@hijinxbassist when i add myOutput.text = "msg" on update() it does change . Unity version 2022.3.30f1

@hijinxbassist i am confused because 1. text changes but not updates and 2. debug prints normal. 3. the link on the discussion mentioned looks like there is a bug that bothers more ppl

Have you tried updating TMP to the latest version?  It could be an issue with a previous version not playing nicely with your unity version.  If you have another version of Unity installed, test your exact setup there as well.  I tested using unity 2020.3.42f with latest TMP on Windows, no issue.

TMP is updated, latest version of unity used...i ll go for a clean install maybe...

Here's what you should do.
[SerializeField] public Text myOutput
And then from there you can do
myOutput.text = "Hello World"
Although I believe this is the scripting for a legacy text component, there are very few cases where you should be using a TextMeshPro instead of a legacy text component. Try using the raw/legacy text instead of TextMeshPro and let me know if that works

This had the same result as TMP. The text changes but it dont updates. I have a debug there that verifies that code reaches there, and also i see the text change that this is another verification. I only managed to update the legacy text if i put it on the update(), what i did for the TMP as well

Oh, the legacy text (raw text) isn't changing either? interesting...

Let it be noted that I'm using version 2023

I mean, Bing AI (which is off of ChatGPT4) said this

Not that ChatGPT is usually helpful, but yknow
